# How to check if there are any duplicate values in a Column in a DataGridview?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, datagridview

I have a DataGridView and before saving data I would like to check if a particular column has any duplicate values in any rows.

```
 If DataGridView1.Rows.Count > 2 Then
            Dim count As Integer = 0
            Dim i As Integer = 0
            While DataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1

                Dim j As Integer = 1


                While DataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1

                    Dim str As String = DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells("ColLedger").Value()
                    Dim str1 As String = DataGridView1.Rows(j).Cells("ColLedger").Value()


                    If str1 = str Then
                        count = count + 1
                    End If

                    j += 1



                End While
                i += 1
            End While


            If count > 0 Then
                MsgBox(count)
            End If
```

I am getting index out of range error. I am not sure what I am doing wrong.

I will accept c# answers too if they can be easily converted using online tools.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work. I think your error lies in the row  `While DataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1` which does not make sense. It is not wrong with without `Option Explicit` though, since the framework can compare integer to boolean (True = 1, False = 0) but that's not what you want here. I always suggest turning on Option Explicit, either by adding it to your code or by simply turning it on in the compilation settings.

```
Dim Count as integer = 0
For i = 0 To dgv.RowCount - 2
  For a = i + 1 To dgv.RowCount - 1
     if dgv.Rows(i).Cells("ColLedger").Value = dgv.Rows(a).Cells("ColLedger").Value Then Count += 1
  Next
Next
MsgBox(Count.ToString)
```

Comment: Nice its works! Btw can you by any chance tell me how can i Check the display text instead of value of combobox? As in `dgv.Rows(a).Cells("ColLedger").Text`

Comment: The display text is just the Value converted to string by the .ToString function. So use `dgv.Rows(a).Cells("ColLedger").Value.ToString()`. I have just edited my answer a bit to exclude duplicates (the 2nd loop only starts after the current position of the first loop).

Comment: @Jens I am populating that combobox using a dataset and I have two seperate fields for its DisplayMember and ValueMember .
`Dim Count as integer = 0
For i = 0 To dgv.RowCount - 2
  For a = i + 1 To dgv.RowCount - 1
     if dgv.Rows(i).Cells("ColLedger").Value = dgv.Rows(a).Cells("ColLedger").Value Then Count += 1
  Next
Next
MsgBox(Count.ToString)` just gets me the value member and not the Display member I was wondering if thats possible in case of Datagridview Combobox

Comment: You should probably formulate a new question for this, I'm not a real expert in this regards. :-)

Comment: @Jens can you help me with my problem ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38420644/make-duplicates-to-single-and-count-in-datagridview-vb-net

Comment: Nice... Helped a lot in VB.Net