# Make Duplicates to Single and Count in Datagridview VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

I got Column Location in my `DataGridView`. I want to **transfer the same values** to another `DataGridView` also **count how many** it was.

Example:

```
DataGridView1          DataGridView2
********************************************
Location               Location       Total
America                America        3
America                Japan          2
Japan                  China          2
China
China
Japan
Ameria
```

How can I get this?

Comment: Can you use the data source of the first grid view and summarize the data into the 2nd?

Comment: @AndrewMortimer How can I do that? just new to this datagridview stuff

Comment: Did your data in the first datagrid come from executing SQL against a database? If so, rerun that SQL with summary type info: select location, count(*) from yourtable group by location.

Comment: Can't I use 7 different tables with left and union join to get the data. Thats why im wondering if I can do that by datagridview function or query :)

Comment: Yes, you can use any number of tables, joined up and summarized.

Comment: @AndrewMortimer see my update for getting the data. How can Implement your way to get what I want?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/117527/discussion-between-andrew-mortimer-and-meyka-jograt).